# to check the end of arrays

Tags: c++

```
main()
{
    char buff[10];

    int a;

    for(int i=0; i<10;i++)

    {

        cin >> buff[i];

        a=sizeof(buff[i]);

        if(a==10)

            cout << "full";

    }

    for(int i=0; i<10;i++)

        cout << buff[i]<<"\n";

}
```

why des the control never comes to  cout << "full"; i am new to coding...when i do dry run it works fine

Comment: Your code doesn't compile, because `buff[i]` is a `char`, while `strlen` requires `const char*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because in this code:

```
a=sizeof(buff[i]);
```

you are getting the size of one of the elements in the `buff` array -- not of the whole array itself.

And since the elements in the array are `char`s, the size will always be one (as dictated by the Standard).

If you are trying to get the index of the element (that is, you want to hit on the 10th element), you need to do this:

```
 if(i==9)
        cout << "full";
```

(`9` instead of `10` because arrays are zero-based, and the 10th item is at `buff[9]`.  First is `buff[0]`, second at `buff[1]`, etc...)

Comment: Sorry had a typo saying `a==9` where i should have said `i==9`.  Fixed

Comment: Note, however, that using `sizeof` on the array itself won't really help -- it'll always give `10`, since the array is defined to be 10 `char`s. Neither will tell anything about the array being "full".

Comment: @Jerry:  good point.  `sizeof` isn't getting you the information you want here

Answer (score 4):

You've defined `buff` to be an array of char. You then look at the `sizeof` one of those char's. The result of the `sizeof` operator depends only on the *type* of object you pass as its argument. In this case, what you're doing is equivalent to `sizeof(char)`, which is defined to be 1 in both C and C++. Since 1 doesn't equal 10, your test will always produce `false`.

Edit: as an aside, my advice would be to back up, regroup, and start over. You generally do *not* want to read a string one character at a time, and until you gain some experience you probably shouldn't use arrays in C++ either. For an initial attempt at reading a string, what you generally want is something like:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
    // define a string object to hold the data
    std::string input;

    // ask the user for some input
    std::cout << "Please type something:";

    // read data from the user:
    std::getline(std::cin, input);

    // we'll print it out again, to show what we got:
    std::cout << input;
    return 0;
}
```

Edit2: I should add that the original attempt (using `strlen`) was at least somewhat closer than the edited version (using `sizeof`). If you decide you really *do* want to read a string one character at a time, correct use of `strlen` *would* tell you when you'd read as much data as you'd made room for. Correct use isn't necessarily entirely obvious though. You'd need something more like this:

```
// Make room for 10 characters *plus* a terminating NUL and fill with NULs:
char buffer[11] = {0}; 

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    std::cin >> buffer[i];

    if (strlen(buffer) == 10)
        std::cout << "full";
}
```

This is still pretty useless though. The `if (strlen ...` doesn't really give you any new or different information from the loop itself -- it will be true when (and only when) the last iteration of the loop is executing. As such, it's result is pretty much the same as if you wrote something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    std::cin >> buffer[i];
}
std::cout << "full";
```

One final point: as shown above, with C-style strings (arrays of char), the string has to be terminated with a NUL character, so you have to define the array with one more element than the maximum length of string you want to be able to store.

Comment: +1: Finally an answer that isn't flat *wrong*!  (Except mine, of course :) )

Comment: @John: Nobody asked you to be condescending. Just because someone uses the word "horribly" in a comment (which I agree was somewhat needlessly confrontational) doesn't mean that incomplete answers don't contribute to the conversation. Vote things down if you'd like, but please keep your head cool.

Comment: @John: I wander with such a poor attitude as yours in this thread how anybody accepts your answers...

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you call `strlen` on `buff[i]`, when I'd guess you want to call `strlen` on `buff`. Remember, `buff[i]` is a single character.

Comment: @John: it's been edited -- before editing, it had `strlen` where it now has `sizeof`.

Comment: @Jerry:  Fair enough.  Then this answer should be deleted

Answer (score 0):

well your test is

a==10

edit because John can't realize when the original code of a post has been edited after answers. so please disregard the following 3 lines because they have already been corrected:

---

and a = strlen(buff[i]);

you are basically comparing 1 character read by cin so always 1 with 10 which always return false hence never prints full

---

what you want to test is

if(i == 9)

why 9, because you are covering from 0 to 9 (<10) in your loop

Comment: Your so high and mighty that you didn't even stop and think that the original code had been edited ??? when Manu originally posted a = strlen(buff[i]) which was an error I was pointing out. but please continue commenting other peoples answer without thinking...

Answer (score -1):

its called zero based indexing.
10 array locations starting from 0.

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 = 10 locations.